# Cannot implicitly convert linq result into viewmodel list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new to MVC and struggling to implement a ViewModel to query multiple tables. Initially my setup worked perfectly but now having reloaded the project I am getting a compilation error as copied below:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CATEGORY>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestProject.Models.CATEGORY>'
```

ViewModel code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestProject.Models
{
  public class COMPCATEGORY
  {
    public List<COMP> Comp { get; set; }
    public List<CATEGORY> Category { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
namespace TestProject.Controllers
{
    public class COMPsController : Controller
    {
        private mattbeaneyEntities1 db = new mattbeaneyEntities1();

        // GET: COMPs
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
          COMPCATEGORY viewModel = new COMPCATEGORY();
          viewModel.Category = db.CATEGORies.ToList();
          viewModel.Comp = db.COMPs.ToList();
          return View(viewModel);
        }
```

DB Context code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;


  public partial class mattbeaneyEntities1 : DbContext
  {
    public mattbeaneyEntities1()
      : base("name=mattbeaneyEntities1")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<CATEGORY> CATEGORies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<COMP> COMPs { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you have two classes named category. On in models, and one in your entity framework declarations??

Comment: Yep, that's done it, for some reason I had a class with CATEGORY and COMP as partial classes. Did away with this and had them as separate full classes. Works a treat.

Comment: Please post your solution as the answer to the question and mark it as the answer. This will help others in the future who may encounter this question by searching.

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky I rolled back your wrongly approved edit suggestion, because you changed the error message to just " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'". That isn't what was in the original question. Pay attention when converting code to non-code: `<` will start being interpreted as the start of an HTML tag.

Comment: @MattBeaney easily done! @KeithPayne; your absolutely right! Done :)

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests it is having trouble with two types by the same name, when we were only expecting one. The namespace is our clue here:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CATEGORY>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestProject.Models.CATEGORY>'
```

Usually there are a couple of things I like to check in this case:

Firstly: are there two classes that share the same name and belong to different namespaces? It's quite easy to do as your project grows!

Secondary: has the main project namespace changed? Sometimes due to a bit of refactoring we change the project name and then end up with two .dll files in the bin folder, which hold duplicate of all our classes - delete the old one!